# Stable vector bundles on an algebraic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, vector-bundles, algebraic-curves, algebraic-vector-bundles

Let $E$ be a stable bundle on a smooth curve of genus $g$. Assume $\chi(E)\leq 0$ or equivalently, $E$ has slope $\leq g-1$. Is there a line bundle $L$ of degree 0 such that $H^0(E\otimes L)=0$ ?

Comment: Really? How about $L=\mathcal O$ ? I should add that the statement is true whenever $E$ is a direct sum of line bundles of degree $\leq g-1$ hence presumably for a 'general' bundle of integer slope $\leq g-1$.